# JAXB Unmarshalling of XML into HashMap

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a complex XML Structure as below which needs to be unmarshalled:

```
<abc>
      <pqr>
        <attribute>name</attribute>
        <entry>
          <priorityKey>
            <class>123</class>
            <reason>abc</reason>
          </prioritykey>
          <priority> 1 </priority>
        </entry>

        <entry>
          <prioritykey>
            <class>456</class>
            <reason>abc1</reason>
          </prioritykey>
          <priority>2</priority>
        </entry>
      </pqr>

      <pqr>
       '''
       '''
      </pqr>
    </abc>
```

**abc** is the root node. It can have multiple **pqr** elements. Each pqr element has **one attribute** node and **multiple entry** nodes. So I believe it will be of type HashMap(entry,attribute).

Each entry in turn has **prioritykey** and **priority** which I believe will be of type HashMap (prioritykey,priority).

Need to unmarshall this xml but not getting how to configure the XMLAdapter

Comment: Why HashMap? Can't it be a class which have list/set of entry in them? Basically I see it as a class Structure i.e. Abc has List of Pqr and each Pqr has a list of Entry -> Entry has attribute -> priority and  class PriorityKey -> has class and reason attribute.

Comment: structure needs to be accessed as (<key,value>) pair

Comment: You can use stax parser here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StAX

Comment: Attribute value will be same. Entry keys will be different.No two Entry objects will be same for "Name" value

Comment: @AshishPatil it is a configuration file and need to be processed via JAXB only...

Comment: Is there any other way of doing instead of using HashMap ?

Answer (score 0):

Here, create the contract first. I created one as part of my learning process...

```
<xs:element name="abc" type="abcType" />

<xs:complexType name="abcType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="pqr" type="pqrType" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="pqrType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="attribute" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="entry" type="entryType" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="entryType" >
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="priorityKey" type="priorityKeyType"
            minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="priority" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="priorityKeyType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="class" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="reason" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"
            maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Copy and save this in an `fileName.xsd` file.
Now, generate JAXB classes or artifacts. If you are using an IDE, then this is simple. Click on the `fileName.xsd` file and you should get some option to generate JAXB artifacts. Otherwise, you can always use `jaxb-xjc.jar` present in the `lib` present in the JAXB download.

Command for the same - `java -jar jaxb-xjc.jar fileName.xsd`.

As the artifacts are in place, you can use them to unmarshall the `xml` content in question.